# Spring - incorrect constructor used

Tags: java, spring

I have two constructors:

```
ctor(String a, String b, char[] c)

ctor(String a, String b, File c)
```

Now, she I do sth like

```
<bean id="myBean"  class="myClass">
    <constructor-arg value="string1" />
    <constructor-arg value="string2" />
    <constructor-arg value="toCharArray" />
```

this is resolved using `File` constructor by spring... any ideas how to stop this?

Comment: This will work there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this in adding the type information to the `constructor-arg` element using the `type` attribute. See the chapter [4.4.1.1 Constructor-based dependency injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) in the Spring documentation for further details.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="myClass">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="string1" />
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="string2" />
  <constructor-arg type="char[]" value="toCharArray" />
</bean>
```